# County Government: Titles and differences between states

Tags: united-states

I am seeking information on the structure of county/parish governments in the United States.

I am specifically seeking information on those bodies that are comparable in nature and authority to the Quorum Courts that exist in the State of Arkansas.

I've given a brief detail of the Quorum Courts below. Something similar for another state would be fantastic, or direction to any resource that covers this layer of government reliably.

---

In the State of Arkansas, the primary County Government is comprised of a body known as Quorum Court and populated by elected Justice of the Peace positions under the guidance of the County Judge. These are partisan positions. The Quorum Court operates independently of municipal governments, and most of their authority does not extend into municipalities.

The existence and duties of Justices of the Peace and the Quorum Court are defined by the Arkansas Constitution and elaborated upon in Arkansas Code Title 14. County Government and Title 16. Practice, Procedure, and Courts. They are also mentioned elsewhere within the Arkansas Code to a lesser extent.

---

Comparable details on governments outside of the United States would be welcome for academic purposes.

Comment: By partisan do you mean they are appointed or they are elected? Are their terms co-terminus with the elected county leaders?

Comment: By partisan, I mean they have a party affiliation and must primary. Many judicial roles are stipulated as nonpartisan in Arkansas and have their general election at the same time as the primaries, but that does not extend here. All Quorum Court members serve 2-year terms. As of 2016, the County Judges serve 4-year terms. Elections are on even years. I hope this is helpful in identifying comparable roles in other states.